# Multiple lines on same plot with incremental logging - wandb

Tags: python, machine-learning, plot, wandb

I am using weights & biases (wandb). I want to group multiple plots into one while using incremental logging, any way to do that?

Say we have 10 metrics, I can add them to the project incrementally, gradually building 10 graphs:

```
import wandb
import math

N_STEPS = 100

wandb.init(project="someProject", name="testMultipleLines")
for epoch in range(N_STEPS):
    log = {}
    log['main_metric'] = epoch / N_STEPS  # some main metric

    # some other metrics I want to have all on 1 plot
    other_metrics = {}
    for j in range(10):
        other_metrics[f'metric_{j}'] = math.sin(j * math.pi * (epoch / N_STEPS))
    log['other_metrics'] = other_metrics

    wandb.log(log)
```

This by default gets presented on the wandb interface as 11 different plots. How can they be grouped through the API (without using the web interface) such that `main_metric` is on one figure and all `other_metrics` are bunched together on a second figure?

Comment: Any resolution to this? I'm trying to solve the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done using the web interface (by adding a panel and making new plots with different y keys) but I am not sure how this can be integrated into code.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish that by plotting your own table.

Additionally, if you'd like to you can also group these metrics into different panes by separating the prefix and the metric name with a "/".

```py
import math
import wandb

N_STEPS = 100

wandb.init(project="someProject", name="testMultipleLines")
table = wandb.Table(columns=["metric", "value", "step"])
for epoch in range(N_STEPS):
    log = {}
    log['main/metric'] = epoch / N_STEPS  # some main metric

    # some other metrics I want to have all on 1 plot
    other_metrics = {}
    for j in range(10):
        log[f'other_metrics/metric_{j}'] = math.sin(j * math.pi * (epoch / N_STEPS))
        table.add_data(f'other_metrics/metric_{j}', log[f'other_metrics/metric_{j}'], wandb.run.step)
    wandb.log(log)

wandb.log({"multiline": wandb.plot_table(
    "wandb/line/v0", table, {"x": "step", "y": "value", "groupKeys": "metric"}, {"title": "Multiline Plot"})
})

wandb.finish()
```

Comment: This is not incremental...